# Unit testing of shell commands called in a python script

Tags: python-3.x, shell, unit-testing, zsh

I am writing unit tests (using Python 3.7, Pytest 3.6 and tox 3.0) for a function that compiles a series of shell commands as a list of strings, and then executes them using the `subprocess` module. The shell commands do the following:

- creates a filename from the function arguments.
- `cd` into a given directory.
- checks for a file with a certain name and removes it if it exist.
- creates a new file with the same name.
- executes a program and pipes the output into the new file.

My test right now is mocking the subprocess module, and then asserting that it was called with a list of strings that contains all the expected commands given some test arguments.

**Is there a way to test that the commands do what they are supposed to?** Right now my test is only checking if the list of commands I feed to the subprocess module is the same as the one I have asserted it to be. This does not tell me whether the commands are *the right ones for what I am trying to achieve*. Rather it only serves as a test on whether I can write down the same string in two different source files.

**Can I simulate the side effects that I expect the shell commands to have?**

Comment: You can use value of `$?` immediately after command execution, If its 0 than your command succeed otherwise there is some issue in your command.
Ex: `if [ "$?" != "0" ]; then echo "ERROR" fi`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question combines two interesting topics: a) Testing code generated from a code generator and b) testing shell code.

For testing code from a generator, you have in principle to do the following: i) test that the generator creates the code that is expected - which you have already done, ii) test that the code snippets / pieces which the generator glues together actually behave (independently and in combination) as it is intended (which in your case are the shell code pieces that in the end together will form a valid shell program) - this is the part about testing shell code that will be adressed below, and iii) test that the inputs that control the generator are correct.

It is comparable with a compiler: i) is the compiler code, ii) are assembly code snippets that the compiler combines to get the resulting assembly program, and iii) is the source code that is given to the compiler to get it compiled.  Once i), ii) and iii) are tested, there is only seldom the need to also test the assembly code (that is, on assembly code level).  In particular, the source code iii) is ideally tested by test frameworks in the same programming language.

In your case it is not so clear how part iii) looks and how it can be tested, though.

Regarding the testing of shell code / shell code snippets: Shell code is dominated by interactions with other executables or the operating system.  The type of problems that lies in interactions in shell code goes in the direction of, am I calling the right executables in the right order with the arguments in the right order with properly formatted argument values, and are the outputs in the form I expect them to be etc. To test all this, you should not apply unit-testing, but integration testing instead.

In your case this means that the shell code snippets should be integration-tested on the different target operating systems (that is, not isolated from the operating system).  And, the various ways in which the generator puts these snippets together should also be integration tested to see if they together operate nicely on the operating system.

However, there can be shell code that is suitable for unit-testing.  This is, for example, code performing computations within the shell, or string manipulations.  I would even consider shell code with calls to certain fundamental tools like basename as suitable for unit-testing (interpreting such tools as being part of the 'standard library' if you like).  In your case as you describe the generated shell code

> creates a filename from the function arguments.

This sounds like one example of a good candidate for 'unit-testing' shell code: This filename creation functionality could be put into a shell function and then be tested in isolation.

Answer (score 1):

With [pytest-mock](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-mock) you can request the `mocker` fixture and then [spy](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-mock#spy) on `subprocess` functions:

```
def test_xxx(mocker):
    mocker.spy(subprocess, 'call')
    subprocess.call(...)
    assert subprocess.call.call_count == 1
```

P.S. Tests with side effects are generally bad practice, so I would recommend running all the shell commands in a `tmpdir` (pytest fixture which creates a temporary directory).